# Using Folder Action to Upload to Amazon s3

Tags: shell, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terminal, automation

Im looking to write a folder action that when run will do the following things: 
1. Compress Image with ImageOtim
2. Upload Compressed Image to a specified Amazon S3 Bucket
3. Copy S3 Link to clipboard
4. Move image out of the "hot" folder to show that the script was successfully executed.

Here is the screenshot of the automator workflow: 
[Automator Workflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2V7P.png)

I have my terminal configured with Homebrew so I can upload to S3 with a command that looks like:

`s3cmd put -P {Local File Path} {Bucket Path}`

but I don't know how to link these two actions together into one cohesive script.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In automator there's an option to "Run Shell Script" as a block in the workflow. Drag that block to where you want it, run `s3cmd put -P {Local File Path} {Bucket Path}` and pass in local file path and bucket path as variables from Automator.